# Semaphore (Mutex) trouble

Tags: c++, multithreading, mutex, semaphore

Let's say I have one Mutex, two threads, one function and one cycle (Pseudo code).
Function:

```
void Update(){
    Mutex.enter();
    ...// time: 10 ms
    Mutex.leave();
}
```

Main.cpp:

```
void main(){
    ...// Starting thread
    while(true)
        Update();
}
```

Thread:

```
void Thread(void *){
    Mutex.enter();
    ... // 
    Mutex.leave();
}
```

But Function calls constantly, so Mutex small time is free. How high chance Thread have to enter in Mutex? If low, how it can be resolved?

Comment: perhaps explicitly yield the processor between update calls? For example there is the `pthread_yield()` function

Comment: You should try very, very hard to find some other design for your data/code that eliminates the continual calling. Yield() is a bandage on a bullet wound.  It might help for a bit, but you're going to need surgery soon.

Comment: When the thread calls Mutex.enter it will block, and as soon as the other thread calls leave the thread should acqire the mutex as it's the only thread at that point requesting it.

Comment: Just remove the `Thread` function. The code will make just as much forward progress without it as with it. If `Update` isn't doing the work you want done, you should fix it. If it is, then what does `Thread` add to your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using boost threads ([link](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/thread.html)), then I'd use [`yield()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/thread/thread_management.html#thread.thread_management.this_thread.yield).  It'll allow any other "waiting" threads to "get a chance" to run.

There's probably a win32 or pthreads way of doing this too.

Edit: and by the way, use `yield()` *outside* of the locks.  If it's inside the locks, obviously that would be useless.

Edit2: And here's the functions for different platforms:

- Win32: `SwitchToThread()` [msdn link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686352%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).
- Linux/Unix pthreads: `pthread_yield()' [link](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/pthread_yield.3.html)

If you're not on any of those platforms, read the descriptions at those links, and look for a function that does the same thing in your framework.

Comment: No, I'm not use boost and other libs.

Comment: yield is indeed what need to be done, and the concept is not limited to boost. there must be a function whatever thread library you use. Like pthread_yield

Comment: What are you using then?  win32?  unix pthreads?  Please give us the information on your compiler/environment.

Comment: @WORLD_DYNAMIC_USER - use the Win32 function I linked above, `SwitchToThread()`.  I even included the msdn link there for a bigger explanation.

Comment: Calling yield at a high rate can have a serious negative impact on system performance. It is primarily there to allow interruptions in longer running high priority tasks.

Comment: @edA-qamort-ora-y - no doubt.  I voted you up so that hopefully the OP realizes this too.

Answer (score 0):

From the pseudo-code you showed it seems like there's no cooperation between threads. If thread2 is lucky to grab the mutex before the call to the first Update() is placed then for the whole lifetime of thread2 Update() functions will not be called. It looks like a flawed design to me. If thread2 is doing the work and 'main' thread is calling Update() function to monitor and report the progress of whatever is happening in thread2 thread routine, then it would make much more sense to have thread1 (the main one) wait on a update_required signal and thread2 (the one that is progressing with work) would do the work, then fill-in a struct variable with all the data needed to report the progress and signal thread1 to use the data and report the progress. Using a ring buffer of such struct variable could eliminate the need for mutexes altogether.